# Почему не отображаются поле blogall, либо не отображаются блоки portfolioall?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вывел через `acf` записи поле `blogall` и оно не отображается, если же поменять местами `portfolioall` и `blogall`, то не отображаются блоки `portfolioall`.

```
<div class="dis__blocks">
    <?php $port_all = get_field('dis_all'); ?>
    <?php foreach( $port_all as $post) { // Переменная должна быть названа обязательно $post (IMPORTANT) 
        $thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'large' );?>
        <div class="dis__block">
            <div class="dis__block__top">
                <div class="dis__block__img">
                    <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="dis__block__info">
                    <div class="dis__block__name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <div class="dis__block__txt"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if(!get_field('portfolioall')) return; ?>
            <?php
            $portfolio_simple = get_field('portfolioall');
            if( $portfolio_simple ):  ?>
                <div class="dis__tabs">
                    <div class="dis__block__tab port_block">
                        <div class="dis__block--tit">Портфолио<span></span></div>
                        <div class="dis__block--content">
                            <div class="simple_blocks">
                                <?php foreach( $portfolio_simple as $post): // Переменная должна быть названа обязательно $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
                                <?php setup_postdata($post);?>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="simple_block">
                                    <span class="simple_block__img">
                                        <img src="<?php echo get_field('img'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="simple_block__title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                                </a>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // ВАЖНО - сбросьте значение $post object чтобы избежать ошибок в дальнейшем коде ?>
                            <a href="/port" class="dis__block--link">Смотреть всё</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
            
            <?php if(!get_field('blogall')) return; ?>
            <?php
                $post_objects = get_field('blogall');
                if( $post_objects ):  ?>
                    <div class="dis__tabs">
                        <div class="dis__block__tab dis_block">
                            <div class="dis__block--tit">Блог дизайнера<span></span></div>
                            <div class="dis__block--content">
                                <div class="simple_blocks">
                                        <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post): // Переменная должна быть названа обязательно $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
                                        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="simple_block">
                                            <span class="simple_block__img">
                                                <img src="<?php echo get_field('img'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="simple_block__title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // ВАЖНО - сбросьте значение $post object чтобы избежать ошибок в дальнейшем коде ?>
                                <a href="/dis" class="dis__block--link">Смотреть всё</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем в проверке на наличие переменных вы выводите return ? Что бы что ?

Comment: Убрал return, все равно не работает(

Comment: Это был вопрос, а не совет... Не понятно зачем в принципе вы тот возврат туда лепили. Вторым параметром в `get_field` обычно передаеться идентификатор. В ващем случаи `$post->ID` возможно это вам поможет. Хотя запись у вас странная, всё в кучу свалено.

Comment: return да, он был без надобности, попробую с $post->ID , если есть время приложи пример

Comment: и если делаю var_dump blogall , выдает null

Comment: https://prnt.sc/kVbqUV9Ur6ge https://prnt.sc/obXpreeakwOQ

Comment: тут в основном проблема в том что если две подряд форички выводятся подряд иили более, отображается только первая форичка с записями остальные Null

Comment: Если возвраеться null, значит запрос н доходит... `if(!get_field('portfolioall', $post->ID))` https://acfwp.ru/category/documentation/ Уверен, ы сможете найти ответ на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил, тем что переставил обьявление переменных до вызова форичек
`<?php $port_all = get_field('dis_all'); $post_objects = get_field('blogall'); ?>`